# How to have a FB application create a personalized post to a user

Tags: post, facebook-graph-api

I've read over some of the developer material and have not seen a way to have an application send facebook users personalized wall posts. For example, FB users who likes "Mustangs" could receive a post from my application when there is news specifcally about Mustangs. However, FB users who didn't select Mustangs would not receive the post. Is there a way to do this on the FB platform for applications?

FYI - The only success I have had is sending a post to a user which appears to have been sent from the user as if the user is posting to themselves. Only upon close inspection can one find the text "via application xyz" next to the post time.

Thanks for taking the time to read and respond.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with any of the frameworks. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/  Also study up on the Graph API (pay attention to the `from` attribute of a feed item, testing it out using the graph API Exporer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Hey DMCS,

I really appreciate you taking the time to reply!

Based on the following developer page I believe the "from" attribute is for an app to read user posts, not create a new post.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Any chance you could direct me to a facebook app which currently sends personalized posts so I could see an example of an app doing it the way I would like to?

Thanks again,

Jeff

Comment: Here's a really simple example of what would be cool - have an app post to a user's wall a welcome message when the user joins the app. The post would be from the app. Has any app implemented that?!

Comment: Did you play with it in the Graph API explorer tool to verify what the `from` field does?  Did it give an error when you set it?  To be good, you've gotta learn how to play with the tools provided.  It does take time.  Happy coding!

Comment: "have an app post to a user's wall a welcome message when the user joins the app."  This would be a breach of the Facebook developer Policy (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) .  Facebook already does post an activity that a user installed your app.  Facebook decides if that activity is posted to the user's wall.

Comment: Hey DMCS, I don't see what item in the policy would be violated. Can you point it out to me? Thanks. :-)

Comment: I'm not an attorney and cannot give you legal clarification.  Please have your company's attorney review the Policy as well as the examples of the policy that facebook provides via links on https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Thanks DMCS. Can anyone give me the name of an example app which writes personalized posts to facebook users? I'd like to see that it can be done. Once I know it's possible I will work on implementing. As far as I can tell, it is not possible.

Comment: Remember, it's legal to post something to a user's wall when they initiate the action.  But you cannot be sneaky and call the act of accepting your application's permissions as free reign to post anything at anytime.

Comment: DMCS - Agree. Why facebook allows an app to post on behalf of the user on the user's wall is beyond me. If an app did that on my wall I would be really annoyed. But that's not what I am trying to do. I want my app to post as MY app on the user's wall.

Comment: Have you played with it on the Graph API Explorer tool yet?  make sure you grab a valid Page access token from me/accounts

Comment: Hi DMCS - Yes, I use the Graph API directly. No luck.